# how to sync two ROS topics by adjusting the time stamp

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Actual Issue:**
I have a topic published with images from a camera and another topic with details of point cloud.
When I plot these two topics, there is a time lag between the two plots.
Is there any method to synchronize this time lag by adjusting the time stamp of point cloud message?

I am using rosbag play for the above mentioned purpose.

**Re-creating the Scenario**
I tried to simulate the above scenario using the below mentioned points:
i. Created a subscriber node which subscribe to the topic(/point_cloud) with point cloud data.
ii. Inside the callback function, I copied the message to a new pointer variable of the same type (sensor_msgs::PointCloud2) and incremented the timestamp by 3sec (The debug print shows that the timestamp has been successfully updated).
iii. Then I published the modified point cloud data in a new topic(/point_cloud_new).
iv. Created two instances of rviz which subscribes to the two topics, /point_cloud and /point_cloud_new respectively.
v. Since the timestamp of /point_cloud_new was incremented by 3sec, I expected a 3sec delay between the two plots in the rviz. But it is not happening.

Since I am new to ROS, I am not sure whether it is the correct method to approach this issue.
Please comment on the actual issue and the scenario re-created.

Please help me to sort out this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234294/how-to-sync-two-ros-topics-by-adjusting-the-time-stamp/) by [A G](https://answers.ros.org/users/26851/a-g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-05-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2016-05-13**:
When you play the bag file are you setting the parameter `use_sim_time` to `true`? That will be a required step for time synchronization when using bag files.

**Comment by [A G](https://answers.ros.org/users/26851/a-g/) on 2016-05-14**:
Yes. I set use_sim_time to true and I am using --clock option while playing the rosbag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Typically, you use a `TimeSynchronizer` for this issue.
See the [wiki for details](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Time_Synchronizer).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A G](https://answers.ros.org/users/26851/a-g/) on 2016-05-13**:
Thanks, mig.
I tried the above mentioned option. But it didn't work.
Also i found a similar issue in the link mentioned below:
http://answers.ros.org/question/146356/synchronise-point-cloud-and-rgb-image-from-the-same-camera/
I even tried with approximate time policy mentioned in the above link.

**Comment by [A G](https://answers.ros.org/users/26851/a-g/) on 2016-05-15**:
An addition to the above comment: When I tried with the TimeSynchronizer and ApproximateTimePolicy method , the behavior was like the callback function was never called.

**Comment by [A G](https://answers.ros.org/users/26851/a-g/) on 2016-05-18**:
Thanks @mig! Approximate time policy mentioned in your link worked.
But I have to increment the timestamp of point cloud by 5sec using a subscriber node before passing it on to the TimeSynchronizer. Otherwise the callback function has never been called!

**Comment by [A G](https://answers.ros.org/users/26851/a-g/) on 2016-05-18**:
@mig @Thomas D New issue-If I play rosbag with the **loop** option,the 1st loop will work,but during 2nd loop,callback function is not called.similar to the issue mentioned in the link http://answers.ros.org/question/106436/usage-of-time-synchronizer-with-rosbag/
Please help me with your suggestions

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-18**:
can't help you there. Also, for a new issue/question, please open a new one.

**Comment by [A G](https://answers.ros.org/users/26851/a-g/) on 2016-05-18**:
ok. Thanks mig!

**Comment by [Master_Matrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/153341/master_matrix/) on 2023-07-21**:
Did you find a solution ?